# S3.getObject() works locally but not on Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a Lambda function triggered by S3 upload. I want to read the contents of the uploaded file by using a readStreamer.

```
const shouldUseXray = false

export async function handleSplitSpreadsheet (event, context) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
  if (shouldUseXray) {
    const { captureAsyncFunc } = require('../../../lib/xray_promise')
    await captureAsyncFunc('handleSplitSpreadsheet', () => {
      log('event', { event })
      processLargeSpreadsheet(event, context)
    })
  } else {
    processLargeSpreadsheet(event, context)
  }
}

export async function processLargeSpreadsheet (event, context) {
  await Promise.all(event.Records.map(async (s3Record) => {
    const bucketName = s3Record.s3.bucket.name
    const s3ObjectMeta = s3Record.s3.object
    const s3ObjectKey = s3ObjectMeta.key
    const s3ObjectSize = s3ObjectMeta.size
    try {
      const s3ObjectStream = s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: s3ObjectKey,
      }).createReadStream()
      s3ObjectStream.setEncoding('utf8')
      s3ObjectStream.on('open', function (data) {
        log('Open:', data)
      })
      s3ObjectStream.on('error', function (data) {
        log('Error: ', data)
      })
      s3ObjectStream.on('data', function (data) {
        log('Data: ', data)
      })
      s3ObjectStream.on('end', function (data) {
        log('End: ', data)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      log('Error: ', err)
    }
  }))
}
```

If I invoke this function locally using `sls invoke --path event.json`, being event.json the exact event that s3 produces, the file is printed on console. 
If I upload a file to S3, nothing is printed. Even if I wrap it all in a try/catch no error is catched.

serverless.yml allows getObject for s3.

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "s3:GetObject"
    - "s3:PutObject"
    - "s3:DeleteObject"
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucketr-foo"
```

Comment: Can you post the entire lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `processLargeSpreadsheet` function is returning before the stream callbacks are called which causes the lambda function to terminate and therefore you don't see those logs when running in lambda. When running locally the callbacks still get executed even though `processLargeSpreadsheet` returns. To fix this you can wrap the stream callbacks in a promise and await that like this:

```
export async function processLargeSpreadsheet (event, context) {
  await Promise.all(event.Records.map(async (s3Record) => {
    const bucketName = s3Record.s3.bucket.name
    const s3ObjectMeta = s3Record.s3.object
    const s3ObjectKey = s3ObjectMeta.key
    const s3ObjectSize = s3ObjectMeta.size

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const s3ObjectStream = s3.getObject({
          Bucket: bucketName,
          Key: s3ObjectKey,
        }).createReadStream()
        s3ObjectStream.setEncoding('utf8')
        s3ObjectStream.on('open', function (data) {
          log('Open:', data)
        })
        s3ObjectStream.on('error', function (data) {
          log('Error: ', data)
          reject();
        })
        s3ObjectStream.on('data', function (data) {
          log('Data: ', data)
        })
        s3ObjectStream.on('end', function (data) {
          log('End: ', data)
          resolve();
        })
      } catch (err) {
        log('Error: ', err)
        reject();
      }
    })
  }))
}
```

You may also need to await `processLargeSpreadSheet` in the `handleSplitSpreadsheet` as well.